# Microsoft Chart Control

Tags: asp.net, charts, controls

Simple question but cannot find answer anywhere.

When using a MS Chart Control of type 'Bar or 'Column'. My X Axis are only labelled every 5 steps. I want it to label every single bar/column on the X Axis.

How do I change this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take look at AxisX and AxisY Interval property:

myChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;